# Java encoding compilation error

Tags: java, encoding, compilation

I try to compile unicode source files using the following command line :

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_05\bin\javac.exe"  -encoding unicodeLittle -nowarn -source 1.5 -classpath . *.java
```

bug I get the following error :

```
error: unsupported encoding: unicodeLittle
```

However unicode seems to be a supported charset : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html

any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try spelling with a capital u:

```
... -encoding UnicodeLittle ...
              ^
```

Keep in mind that Java is case-sensitive in many regards, even on Windows machines.